# Odd Angular2 and Babel transpile

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, babeljs

Using Angular 2 with Typescript.  Bundling with Webpack and using babili plugin.  I am getting an error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token ?`

I have traced it back to this transpiled snippet:

```
z=/^(?:([^:/?#.]+):)?(?://(?:([^/?#]*)@)?([\w\d\-\u0100-\uffff.%]*)(?::([0-9]+))?)?([^?#]+)?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/
```

The offensive piece is `?://`

I have further tracked this down to url_resolver.js in @angular/compiler

````
var /** @type {?} */ _splitRe = new RegExp('^' +
'(?:' +
'([^:/?#.]+)' +
// used by other URL parts such as :,
// ?, /, #, and .
':)?' +
'(?://' +
'(?:([^/?#]*)@)?' +
'([\\w\\d\\-\\u0100-\\uffff.%]*)' +
// digits, dashes, dots, percent
// escapes, and unicode characters.
'(?::([0-9]+))?' +
')?' +
'([^?#]+)?' +
'(?:\\?([^#]*))?' +
'(?:#(.*))?' +
'$');
```
````

the line that reads: `'(?://' +`

If I edit the transpiled code to remove the `//` everything seems to work.  If I change it to `\/\/` everything seems to work.

Obviously I cannot just keep editing this file on each build.  Problem is I don't know where the actual problem lies.  Is it with babel or with the angular code?  I hate to clutter their issues (the angular issues are rather strict in their submission guidelines) so I figured I'd ask this excellent community.

---

Some additional info in case it is needed:

tsconfig:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "es5",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "removeComments": false,
   "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "typings",
    "node_modules",
    "server"
   ],
  "files": []
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

relevant (hopefully) portion of webpack.config.js

```
atlOptions = 'transpileOnly=true&configFileName=tsconfig.prod.json'
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.ts$/,
  loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions, 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader'],
  exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
})

config.plugins.push(new BabiliPlugin({comments: false, mangle: false}))
```

Right now I have none of the babel stuff for dev workflow so this is not causing problems there - just for a production build.